# I'm Getting The Error: 'void' type not allowed here

Tags: java, arrays, void

```
public static void displayMenu(String[] name, double[] price) {
 int i = 0;
 double pr = 0;
 System.out.println("Welcome to our store, we have the following. Please enter what you would like: ");
 for (int j = 0; j < name.length; j++) {
      pr = price[j];
      System.out.println((j + 1) + " - for " + name[j] + " (" + pr + ")");
 }
 System.out.println("0 - for checkout");
}
```

capitalize(name) is a void method that takes an array of strings as a parameter.

```
public static void capitalize(String[] name) {
  String s = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
     s = name[i];
     s = s.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
     System.out.println(s);
  }                    
}
```

I wanted to use the "upper/lower cased" version of the String array but it gives an error:

```
error: 'void' type not allowed here
     System.out.println((j + 1) + " - for " + capitalize(name) + " (" + pr + ")");
                                                        ^
```

What can i do about this?
*NOTE = It has to be done with a void method.

Comment: You should return the value, not print it out.

Comment: If `capitalize()` doesn't return anything, what value is `capitalize(name)` supposed to return?

Comment: yes i should return the value but i cannot because it has to be done with a void method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original answer was indeed wrong. If you **need** to return void, instead of printing it, replace in the array (or create a new array with capitalized Strings):

```
public void capitalize(String[] name) {
  String s = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
     s = name[i];
     s = s.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
     name[i] = s;
  }                    
}
```

Then, in your print statement, print out name[j] (or whatever you called the new array, if you want to preserve original).

Comment: But i need to use a void method. Otherwise that would be easy, i would use a method String[] and return it. That isnt the point sadly.

Comment: oh yeah assigning it back to array was the right solution, thanks! However, my displaying statement is in another void method (its not main method), which i forgot to include. What can i do about that? (I edited to put the whole display method, sorry that i didnt earlier, its my first question in this platform)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print the result of a void method which is not allowed. If you cannot change the type of the method, then have the method modify an instance variable (which could be an array like you have) and print that variable (array) instead. You could even just print the value inside the void method after each iteration.

Say your instance variable was this `String[] name`. Then you could do this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < name.length; j++) {
    pr = price[j];
    capitalize(name);
    System.out.println((j + 1) + " - for " + name[j] + " (" + pr + ")");
}
```

Your capitalize method:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
     this.name[i] = name[i].substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + name[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();
     System.out.println(this.name[i]); //this is optional if you're okay with printing here instead of where the capitalize method gets called
  }
```